# Error: anyDuplicated(self$user.df$region) == 0 is not TRUE

Tags: r, choropleth, choroplethr

I am self-teaching R to me and at the moment I am having a look on Choropleths in R. For this I am using the packages 'choroplethr' and 'choroplethrAdmin1'.

After plotting all the examples from the instruction of these packages I wanted to plot a map of Germany's administrative 1 levels with random values. So I tried to to use the `admin_1choropleth` command. The help functions says that the command needs a dataset with two specific columns:

- one called 'regions' which includes regions with the same spelling as they are in the 'admin1.regions'-dataset provided by the package
- a second which is called 'value' to match the including values to the regions

For example this code produces a map of Japans Population per km² using the dataset:'df_japan_census' which contains a column called 'value' and one called 'region'

```
admin1_choropleth("japan",
              df_japan_census,
              "Japan Population",
              "per km²")
```

So for plotting an example map of Germany I just used the 'admin1.regions'-dataset (because it includes the regions needed) and added a column 'value' 
to it. Then I tried to plot it. This is how the code is looking:

```
admin1.regions$value<-3:4401 #the numbers are just placeholders
admin1_choropleth("germany",admin1.regions)
```

But now I am getting this Error:

> Error: anyDuplicated(self$user.df$region) == 0 is not TRUE

This is my first questions on stackoverflow and I am neither a natural English speaker or a programmer, so I hope you can understand my problem.

If you are having any questions do not hesitate to ask me.

Best,
Marcel

P.S.: To make it easier for you, this should be all you need to reproduce the Error.

```
install.packages("choroplethr")
library(choroplethr)
install.packages("choroplethrAdmin1")
install.packages("ggplot2")
library(choroplethrAdmin1)
library(ggplot2)

admin1.regions$value<-3:4401
admin1_choropleth("germany",admin1.regions)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get this error is due to duplicates in column `region` of `admin1.regions`. If you use `unique(admin1.regions$region)` you will get a vector of length 4358, while the orignal dataset is 4399 (so 41 duplicates).

How to tackle this problem? You only need the entries containing `"germany"`, so remove all the non-`"gemany"` entries.

```
admin1.regions$value<-3:4401 #the numbers are just placeholders
admin1.regions1 <- admin1.regions[which(admin1.regions$country == "germany"),]
admin1_choropleth("germany",admin1.regions)
```

Now your code should work.

PS. cool name

Comment: Thanks Marcel, you have a nice name too. :D 

When I use the data of  'admin1.regions1' in the last line it is perfectly working! 

Thank you so much!